# how to stop echo statement from echoing multiple times while inside nested loops

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, nested, nested-loops

I have the following query structure

**Structure**

```
//note the value in $array isan array sent from the client side script
$q1 = mysqli_query($db,'query stuff')or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($q1) >=1 )
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) // while loop 1
    {
        $q2 = mysqli_query($db,'query stuff') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
        if(mysqli_num_rows($q2)>=1)
        {
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($2)) // while loop 2
            {
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++) // forloop
                {
                    if( \\validate conditions )
                    {
                        echo $i;//echoes 0101 instead of 01
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** The above code contains 2 while loops and 1 for loop.The for loop is nested in one while which is in turn nested in another while loop. When I output the code the expected output is `01` but instead it returns `0101`

How do i stop this from hapenning

---

What i tried

i have tried the following structure

```
            .....
            $tab_exists = false;
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc(q2))//while loop 2
            {
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++) // for loop
                {
                       if(!$tab_exists)
                       {
                           echo $i;//echoes 00 instead of 01
                           $tab_exists = true;
                       }
                }
            }
```

**Result of above structure:** In the above code the $i in the statement does not increment

Comment: Very hard to work out where your problem lies when the contrived example strips out any clues to the original intention. Clearly you are making more iterations of the inner loop than expected, buy why that is remains unknown. Perhaps simply limiting output via a counter will work, but i doubt thats a good solution. Please provide more details

Comment: the inner loop (ie the for loop) exisists because Im sending an array of values to the server for validation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($db,'query stuff')or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
$count =0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($q1) >=1 )
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $q2 = mysqli_query($db,'query stuff') or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
        if(mysqli_num_rows($q2)>=1)
        {
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($2))
            {
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++)
                {
                    if( \\validate conditions && $count<=2)
                    {
                        echo $i;//echoes 0101 instead of 01
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why should the condition be `count<=2` ?